# Are all diagrams commutative?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I begin to learn category theory. The following three definitions are provided.

*Definition 1*. Two morphisms $f\colon a \to b$ and $g\colon c \to d$ are *the same* if and only if $a = c$ and $c = d$.

*Definition 2*. A *diagram* is a collection of objects and morphisms from a category.

**Definition 3**. A diagram is called *commutative*, if any composable sequence of morphisms with the same endpoints (of a sequence) results in the same composite.

Then, as the endpoints of sequences are the same, the sources and the targets of the composites are the same, so are all diagrams commutative? I suspect at least one definition is not correct, or I don't understand some parts of them.

Comment: Definition 1 is wrong. Have you tried an example such as the category of sets?

Comment: Even with a corrected Definition 1: Suppose you have functions $f \colon X \to Y$, $g \colon Y \to Z$ and $h \colon X \to Z$ with $h \ne f \circ g$. If I understand everything correctly, the corresponding diagram is not commutative.

Comment: The morphisms of a category are always some kind of mathematical object (often they are functions, but not always). Two morphisms are the same (i.e. equal) if they are equal as mathematical objects. For instance, if your morphisms are functions, then two morphisms are equal if they are the same function, if your morphisms are ordered pairs, then they are equal if they are the same ordered pair, etc.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you say that two morphisms are the same if they are the same mathematical object. Then, you would have to define what does it mean for two mathematical objects to be the same. The point is, morphisms don't have to be usual mathematical objects such as functions. I can have a category with only one object $a$, and an identity morphism $1_a$. I don't have to specify what else $a$ is, neither what else $1_a$ is. $a$ is an object and $1_a$ is a morphism, that's it.

Comment: If you want me to see your comment, you need to write @Joe in it. There is not one definition for what it means for two mathematical objects to be the same. Two functions are equal if they have the same domain, codomain, and graph. Two ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are equal if $a=c$ and $b=d$, etc.

Comment: You *can* define a category with only one object and one morphism as you have done, but your description has not specified a single category. There are *many* mathematical objects $a$, and each one of them gives rise to a different category with one object (in fact, even if you do specify $a$, you still have infinitely many choices for how you define $1_a$). I might just as well say "I could let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, and I don't have to specify what $f(0)$ is". Well, yes, but clearly I have not defined a unique function $f$.

Comment: The point is that although there are technically infinitely many categories with one object, they all "behave in the same way" as categories if you forget about what the underlying objects are. This is formalised with the notion of isomorphisms of categories, and equivalence of categories.

Comment: @Joe, didn't you mean I had to tag you, if you were supposed to be notified about my comment? You can clearly see it if you answer it. So, do you say there is no way of telling whether two morphisms are the same, if we do not know what other mathematical objects with defined $=$ they correspond to?

Comment: I just meant that it was only good fortune that I saw your comment, because I didn't get a notification that you wrote it. If you have a fixed category $\mathcal C$, and morphisms $f$ and $g$, then the only way to determine whether $f$ equals $g$ is to look at what mathematical objects they are, yes.

Comment: @JakubKaczor: Also, a morphism isn't a new mathematical object like a function or an ordered pair is. If you have two collections $\operatorname{Hom}$ and $\operatorname{Obj}$, along with functions $\operatorname{dom}$ and $\operatorname{cod}$ and $\circ$, satisfying certain axioms, then you have a category (sometimes categories are defined differently to this, but the idea is the same). For a fixed category $\mathcal C$, we call the members of $\operatorname{Hom}$ "morphisms", and that's it.

Comment: This is similar to how "vector" doesn't really have a definition in modern mathematics. Instead, you define what a vector space is, and then by convention, for a given vector space $V$, you call its members "vectors". It's just a linguistic convention.

Comment: Incidentally, I think the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3054271/why-doesnt-the-definition-of-a-category-require-an-explicit-notion-of-morphisms) will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3):

The first definition doesn't make sense. Given two objects in a category, there can be many distinct morphisms from one to the other. To answer your main question: no, not every diagram is commutative. For example, in the category of sets, a diagram could look like this:

[image]

In this example, you have three sets $X,Y,Z$, as well as functions $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y \to Z$, and $h:X \to Z$. *Commutativity* of the diagram means that $h = g\circ f$. This is certainly not the case if you take specific functions $f,g$ and an arbitrary $h$ (write down explicit examples).

Comment: So, how would you define *sameness* of morphisms? For a category $\mathcal C$, the two morphisms $f: a \to b$ and $g\colon c \to d$ are the same if and only if $a = c, b = d$ and there is only one morphism $h \in \operatorname {hom} {\mathcal C}$, such that $h\colon a \to d$? Then, will the diagram you presented be commutative, if we remove $h$ from the category?

Comment: What it means for morphisms to be the same depends on the category you're working with. In the category of sets, functions $f,g:X \to Y$ are equal if $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. But in the [naive homotopy category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category), for example, morphisms represented by continuous maps $f,g$ are equal if $f$ is homotopic to $g$.

Comment: I believe you assume a category has to be consisted of some existing mathematical objects, for which $=$ is already defined. Does it?

Comment: Would you say about [this diagram from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Commutative_square.svg), that it is not necessarily commutative, because we do not know when $hf = kg$, because we don't know what underlying mathematical objects are, if they are any?

Comment: The usual definition of a category requires morphisms to form a class or a set, in which there is a notion of equality, yes.

Comment: And indeed, there is no way to know if that square diagram is commutative, a priori.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a category does not say whether two morphisms are equal in general. This is only given for specific composites containing identity. Therefore, the first definition is not general, thus not every diagram is commutative.

You can define a general category without specifying what other mathematical objects the objects and morphisms are. Then, you cannot always determine whether a diagram is commutative, because you have no way of determining whether two composites are the same, that is, checking the third definition. Perhaps you can say that if you cannot check the definition, then it is not fulfilled, thus a diagram is not commutative.

An example of a category in which you can tell whether any diagram is commutative without specifying what other mathematical objects the objects and morphisms are, is any category that contains only identity morphisms. There, any diagram commutes.

An example of a specific category where a diagram does not commute because of the notion of equality is given by @AlexProvost in his answer.

---

This answer is how I would like the question to be answered, but it is based on the effort of others. I would like to thank you all for comments and answers, but especially @AlexProvost, @Joe, and @NoahSchweber.